# Доброго времени суток всем в этом чатике!

Tags: предложение, приветствия

Доброго времени суток! Довольно часто вопросы начинаются с пожелания доброго времени суток. И большинство ручных правок удаляет его.

Искусственный интеллект SO в какой-то степени проверяет вопросы перед отправкой. Возможно стоит добавить правило на вхождение "Доброго времени суток" и ненавязчиво принудительно отобразить соответствующую подсказку на красном фоне.

Answer (score 7):

Кричать на участника-новичка красным фоном, если он посмел поздороваться, нарушив неочевидное правило — пожалуй, слишком сурово. Лучше молча удалять текст при отправке сообщения. Собственно, на большом СО именно это и происходит.

Answer (score 2):

Необязательно ругаться, чтобы объяснить, чего здесь ждут. Вместо подсказки на красном фоне сайт может отвечать: "Спасибо :) А вам тоже!".

И после этого автоматически удалять из поста "доброе время суток" или предлагать отредактировать сообщение, чтобы оно начиналось с сути дела.

Comment: Где-то в документации написано про все эти преамбулы, которые не нужны и от которых следует воздержаться и сразу переходить к вопросу. Но это совсем другая проблема -- что никто не хочет читать эту документацию.