# Заменить автоматическое удаление приветствий на недопущение публикации

Tags: предложение, вопросы, приветствия

Недавно была предложена инициатива «[Автоматическое удаление приветствий](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6666/208074)».

В связи с [высказанными опасениями](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6671/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b9#comment26087_6674):

> Так все зависит от того, какая регулярка. Русский язык, к сожалению, куда богаче английского. Если хватит воли создать километровую регулярку, которая корректно будет вырезать вещи типа "Приветствую вас, уважаемые знатоки", то нет вопросов. А если она будет превращать это в "вас, уважаемые знатоки", заставляя думать что курил автор, (и вопрос все равно придется править вручную), тогда какой смысл?

Предлагаю не вырезать ключевые слова, а попросту не давать публиковать сообщения с ними по аналогии с запретом на короткие тексты.

Тогда можно будет:

- сократить список ключевых слов, убрав оттуда различные варианты одной и той же фразы (пример: `доброе утро всем`, `добрый вечер всем` и `добрый вечер коллеги` дублируют `доброе утро` и `добрый вечер`),
- не ломать голову насчёт смысловой корректности частей,остающихся после отрезания.

Вот пример того, как это могло бы выглядеть:

> [image: Запрет приветствий при задании вопроса]

Comment: Отпугнет новичков, которые не поймут что происходит. Имхо, не так еще популярен ресурс, чтобы принимать такие меры, потенциально снижающие его посещаемость

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, речь идет не о зачеркивании, а об `не давать публиковать сообщения с ними `

Comment: @АндрейNOP сколько уже можно трястись над индивидуумами со слабой психикой? Тут не детский сад и поттерание сопелек и задниц. Надо выходить из способа общения принятых в соц.сетюшечек и твиттерюшечках, а не деградировать за компанию

Comment: @АлексейШиманский но ведь могут и бинайсом ромбовидным шандарахнуть за такое!

Comment: Этот вариант уже лучше чем удаление, на мой взгляд можно ещё мягче делать это не как запрет, а как рекомендацию (не обязательную к исполнению).

Comment: в дополнение - будет не лишним в предупреждении отображать проблемное слово/фразу, из-за которого появляется предупреждение.

Comment: @Alex `отображать проблемное слово/фразу, из-за которого появляется предупреждение` - включать программно камеру, фотографировать, выводить фото на экран с красной стрелкой указывающей на неe с текстом "У нас тут проблемка! Пожалуйста исправьте её. P.S. Не используйте приветсвия в заголовках."

Comment: О, похожий вопрос https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3501/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B2-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B5

Comment: Не могли бы вы опубликовать ваш вопрос ответом к [исходному вопросу](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/465/)? Предложение очень хорошее и не хотелось бы его потерять!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, сделано. Надо ли добавлять там плашку с отсылкой сюда? Надо ли удалять этот вопрос (и если да, то что делать с ответами и комментариями)?

Comment: @Arhad Пожалуйста, не удаляйте вопрос. Ссылка не помешает. Жалко, что сразу не нашли предыдущее обсуждение.

Answer (score 6):

Посмотрел внимательнее английскую регулярку, у нее скорее обратная проблема кстати. Удаляется весь блок текста от приветствия до следующего знака препинания. Т.е. сложные приветствия будут нормально удаляться, зато есть риск прибить вместе с ними что-то полезное, если автор не в состоянии нормально поставить знаки препинания. И на испанской мете уже было нытье, что исчезают предложения с hay (которое, видимо, у них вводное слово).

В связи с этим, наверное да, лучше сделать так. Запрет будет куда эффективнее автоматического вырезания.

Comment: Не желающие соблюдать правила языка должны страдать!

Comment: Испанцев уже [удовлетворили](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304996/339911), так что не надо бояться очень сильно удалений. А если бы был запрет на публикацию — это вызвало бы, наверное, еще больше гнева.

Comment: @alexolut Если красное сообщение будет содержательным, пользователь легко сможет переформулировать текст, так чтобы проблемная фраза не была в начале. Гнев может вызвать все что угодно, это да, но большая проблема если движок будет молча коверкать вопросы, так что пользователи не будут даже понимать, что происходит.

Comment: @alexolut у Вас есть все шансы на то, чтобы разделить участь "нежелающих" ;)

Answer (score 3):

Я однажды хотел спросить на SO какой-то вопрос, это было ещё до того как я разобрался в тонкостях работы SO. Набрал текст, на мой взгляд текст адекватный, при этом SO текст не пропустил, по-моему с предупреждением что текст короткий.
Я минут 10-15 переформулировал вопрос, добавляя пустую информацию, чтобы движок всё же пропустил мой вопрос. При этом так и не понял, и до сих пор не понимаю, почему мой вопрос не принимался. Куча потраченного времени впустую + разочарование от странного поведения движка. Плюс до сих пор страх, что вопрос не пропустят из-за того, что он слишком короткий, поэтому если вопрос получается коротким, я стараюсь его дополнить по виду полезной информацией, но по сути которая ничего в вопрос не добавляет. Кстати, после этого видел много более коротких вопросов чем мой, которые система пропускала.

Непонятные, странные ограничения могут навсегда отвадить пользователей от сайта.

Comment: Решение для публикации коротких вопросов [есть](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3393/176217).

Comment: @alexolut ясно, спасибо, буду знать. но обычные пользователи этого не знают, а бороться с движком мало приятного.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин я вот с вами согласен, но пока что это предложение намного лучше того, где предлагают приветствия вырезать регуляркой ) имхо ;)